# Set starting point of Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've got an EditText with my own style. Basically it's a border for the EditText. The problem is that the text starts over this border so it's not very nice. Is there a way of set the starting point of the text in an EditText?

Comment: you can add some default space(one or two), then start text.

Comment: give padding at starting side in layout like android:paddingLeft="10dp"

Comment: You should copy and paste it as an answer Deepak so i could vote you up!Definately it works!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give padding at starting side in layout like this

```
<EditText 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ...
  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
/>
```